# Sign in with Apple strange behaviour / React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, apple-sign-in, sign-in-with-apple

The new version of my application was rejected due to "app loading indefinitely after Sign in with Apple". They tested it on iOS 14.6, iPhone and iPad.

I didn't change anything about this part on the new version, and it works fine on Android and web site.

My config is **React Native** and the package **invertase/react-native-apple-authentication**.

Here are the tests I did and the informations I gathered:

Some people say Apple sign in doesn't work at all on simulator, but others say it works on simulator with iOS 13.

So I tested it on a simulator with iOS 14: it loads indefinitely.

Then I tested it on a simulator with iOS 13: it loads then nothing happens (it stays on my authentification screen).

Then I tested it on a real device, iPhone SE with iOS 14, and it's another problem: when I click on the button, it always shows the pop-up for going into the settings and logging, even if I'm already logged. I have to connect to iCloud for Apple sign in to work, which I don't think was a thing before.

Are there known new issues with Apple sign in?

Comment: Sign In with Apple has always required you to be logged into iCloud; It is linked to the user's iCloud Apple ID

Comment: @Paulw11Hmm ok thanks, I didn't remember that. So I guess it's once again Apple testers using simulators for testing Apple sign in despite it doesn't work on simulator.

Comment: Apple definitely reviews on real devices, typically iPads. You submit a device build,  it a simulator build so they can't run on a simulator.

Comment: I didn't change anything and replied to them saying "Apple sign in doesn't work en simulators" and they validated my build. A lot of users say they have the same problem and have to submit twice, explaining to Apple their sign in doesn't work en simulator.